# Enable An Option from select tag when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript

There is a select dropdown with one of the options initially disabled. What I want is to enable that option **only** when the checkbox is clicked. Do not know how to do this on single option instead I'm enabling/disabling the entire select dropdown :(.

```
    <input type='checkbox' id='details' name='form_details<?php if ($form_details) echo ' checked'; ?> onchange='enableOption()';>

   <select name='form_summarize_by' id='summarize_by'>
   <?php
    echo " <option value='0'>Orange</option>\n";
    echo " <option value='1'" . (!$form_details ? "disabled='disabled'":"" ) . ">Pear</option>";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function enableOption(){
    if(document.getElementById('details').checked == true)
    {
     document.getElementById('summarize_by').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('summarize_by').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The disabled attribute is boolean, so no value should be given to it. i.e. `<option disabled/>` vs `<option disabled="disabled"/>`

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an id on the option, then change the disabled attribute on the option instead of the whole select. It also helps to have spaces between attributes.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='details' name='form_details' <?php if ($form_details) echo ' checked'; ?> onchange='enableOption()';>

<select name='form_summarize_by' id='summarize_by'>
<?php
    echo " <option value='0'>Orange</option>\n";
    echo " <option id="summarize_by_option" value='1' " . (!$form_details ? "disabled":"" ) . " >Pear</option>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableOption(){
    if(document.getElementById('details').checked == true)
    {
     document.getElementById('summarize_by_option').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('summarize_by_option').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox and select element are in a form, on the checkbox you can do:

```
onclick="this.form.form_summarize_by.options[1].disabled = this.checked;"
```

or use a function:

```
onclick="updateDisabled(this);"
```

and the function:

```
function updateDisabled(cb) {
  cb.form.form_summarize_by.options[1].disabled = cb.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! I was able to solve it like this:

```
 function enableOption(){
    if(document.getElementById('details').checked == true)
    {

     document.getElementById('summarize_by').options[1].disabled=false;

    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('summarize_by').options[1].disabled=true;
    }
 }
```